# code obfuscation for an Angular 4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to protect my source code and does not want the ts and js files to be exposing entire source code. Could you please suggest if there is a library that I can use to prevent this?

Comment: The same tools you would use for JS. Angular is compiled to JavaScript and then you can use the same tools on this build output.

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?q=tools+for+offuscate+javascript&oq=tools+for+offuscate+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.8847j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=tools+for+obfuscate+javascript

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-protect-javascript

Comment: I have an angular app acting as a client which is completely deployed on a different server and an express app deployed in different server used to serve rest api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com) for Javascript files. I don't think they work with typescript, but I like protecting my app through them.

You have to pay to use it, but your code won't timeout after protecting it, and they offer good support too for their app.

I use Jscrambler to obfuscate classes, methods, and variables, but they also offer code locks, and an anti-tampering/anti-debugging feature.

Comment: Any open source libraries which does the same as Jscrwmbler?

Comment: From what I've tested, no. Open source programs I testes were also easily reversible.